# Is there is any way to authenticate IAM User

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Can we find that the AWS IAM User is valid using oAuth or some other authentication flow, from third pary application?

Comment: You can use any OIDC compliant identity provider and map IAM Role to this identity. You can either call `sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity` to exchange OIDC ID token for STS credentials or you can use Cognito service.

Comment: Hi Matus, this can be used to authtenicate third party users using OIDC and getting token by which we could get STS credentials but I need to authenticate IAM user is there is any way?

Comment: What do you mean authenticate IAM user? IAM users are authenticated by either login/password or access key/secret access key depending on the type of required access.

Comment: I am asking that Is there is any way that IAM user could signin through oauth2 or some other way we get token and through that we could get Credentials to access AWS resources..

Comment: But that question makes no sense. IAM users have credentials to access AWS resources, again, those are access key id and secret access key which you can use in SDK/CLI to make programmatic API calls. So the question how to get them through OAuth2 is pointless. OIDC and SAML is useful only when you want to make federated access, meaning that you don't have IAM users.

Answer (score 3):

There are several examples of how you can authenticate your users in the AWS documentation. IAM supports [Identity Federation](https://aws.amazon.com/identity/federation/) in various ways depending on your use case.

For IAM users there is [AWS Single Sign-On](https://aws.amazon.com/single-sign-on/), integration with [Microsoft Active Directory](https://aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/active-directory/), [configuration of SAML 2.0 Federated Users](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_enable-console-saml.html), [AD FS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-implement-federated-api-and-cli-access-using-saml-2-0-and-ad-fs/), etc.

For non-IAM users, typically the end users of your application, you can create an [Cognito User Pool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools.html) and then [configure Identity Providers for Your User Pool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-identity-provider.html). Options include Facebook, Google and Amazon accounts, as well as OIDC (OpenID Connect) and SAML IdP (Identity Provider).

Please see the links above to find more information, references and examples.

Comment: Hii matsev, I have gone through Identity Federaiton but it will be used to authenticate and authroize users of third pary application using cognito or other identity providers...But, my usecase is to authenticate IAM user from third pary application.